# How to animate fadein fadeout in reactnative with zindex?

Tags: reactjs, css, react-native, animation

I am trying to animate a message always top to screen which has a scrollable view.
Which works great on click on `onButtonClick` from my FlatList component. But there's a small issue, as the `Animated.View` position absolute its always at the top of the screen, due to this The top most element of the Flatlist isnt clickable. I tried with the zIndex, seems doesnt effect. 
How do I fix the click keeping the animation as works right now?

```
//styles
 notification: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 50,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    zIndex: 100
  },
  notificationWrapper: {
    height: 100,
    width: 270,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 40,
    marginLeft: 28,
    marginRight: 28,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingLeft: 28
  }
```

```
//js

onButtonClick = () => {
    this.fadeIn.setValue(0);
    Animated.timing(
      this.fadeIn,           
      {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 1000,
      }
    ).start(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.fadeOut();
      }, 2000);
    });
}

fadeOut = () => {
    this.fadeIn.setValue(1);
    Animated.timing(
       this.fadeIn,
       {
         toValue: 0,
         duration: 1000,
       }
    ).start();
}
<Fragment>
  <ScrollView style={[styles.mainContainer, {flex: 1}]}>
   <FlatList
     style={{ paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 20, paddingRight: 20 }}
     data={favouriteData}
     keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
     renderItem={this.rendeCampus}
   />
 </ScrollView>
   <Animated.View                 
     style={[styles.notification, {opacity: this.fadeIn, zIndex: 
          this.fadeIn}]}
    >
      <View style={styles.notificationWrapper}>
        <Text style={{
          fontSize: 12,
          lineHeight: 15,
          color: 'rgba(42,36,66,1)',
          width: 270
        }}>This restaurant has been added to your favourites list</Text>
      </View>
   </Animated.View>
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing everything else is at default `zIndex: 0`

Try using an interpolation like this:

```
this.zAnimate = this.fadeIn.interpolate({
  inputRange: [ 0, 1],
  outputRange: [-1, 9]
})
```

And assign `this.zAnimate` to your `zIndex`.  You might have to play with the outputRange a little bit depending on when exactly you want it to fade behind, come in front.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to push away the view using `transform`.
For example.

```
this.fadeIn.setValue(1);
    Animated.timing(
       this.fadeIn,
       {
         toValue: 0,
         duration: 1000,
       }
    ).start(() => {
      this.transform.setValue(-200);
    });
```